# Is Mac address in android always available when wifi is ON?

Tags: android, mac-address

My app runs on android. It does not work without wifi and not even installed on such systems
The app connects to a server over WIFI and has to pass it a unique device identifier.
The app may have other installations on the same phone/tablet and whenever any of them connect to server they all should pass the same unique identifier.

Mac address seems to be be the best choice given the pre-requisites of running app.

So the question is can I trust that mac address will always be available when WIFI is available and ON ?

Comment: Device identification on Android is a messy, messy topic. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: We use MAC addresses for identification and haven't had any problems. I think this sounds like a perfect solution for what you have

Answer (score 1):

Any device that uses WIFI must have a MAC address to make it work, so yes, I think (but I'm not going to guarantee) that you can trust the MAC address to always be available with WIFI.

Seems like it should work for your case too since you require WIFI to install the app, it'll always be unique to each device.